# Não permitir digitar espaço em maskedTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

No `windowsforms` qual a maneira mais simples de se evitar a digitação espaços em um controle `maskedTextBox` ?

Comment: Que mascara esta a usar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No evento KeyDown do maskedTextBox coloque o seguinte código abaixo:

```
private void maskedTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Outro modo utilizando o evento KeyPress, por que?

O Evento KeyPress vai disparar enquanto o usuário estiver pressionando a tecla, diferente do que acontece no KeyDown.

```
private void maskedTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        e.Handled = e.KeyChar == ' ';
}
```

Fonte: http://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/qual-a-diferenca-entre-o-onkeydown-e-o-onkeypress/214947

Answer (score 1):

Talvez isso irá te ajudar me ajuda bastante no meu projeto.

```
    private void maskedTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //não permitir augumas coisas 
        if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || //Letras

            char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar) || //Símbolos

            char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar)) //Espaço

            e.Handled = true; //Não permitir

        // VERIFICAR . - ; entre outros
        if (!char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && !(e.KeyChar == ',') && !(e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(8)))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        //só permitir digitar uma vez a virgula
        if (e.KeyChar == ','
            && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf(',') > -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```